# Same two codes , but still one of them has error in c [CODE BLOCKS]-[VS2010]

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, codeblocks

I wrote a code and it compiles perfectly in CodeBlocks 13.12 with no errors !
i copied the same code to VS2010 it shows 1 error:

```
IntelliSense: identifier "malloc" is undefined
```

CodeBlocks Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define maxLength 4
typedef short int *set;

void func(set *a)
{
    *a=malloc(maxLength*sizeof(set));
    (*a)[0]=10;
    (*a)[1]=13;
    (*a)[2]=15;
}

void main()
{
    set a;
    func(&a);
    printf("%d %d %d",a[0],a[1],a[2]);

}
```

VS2010 Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxLength 4
typedef short int *set;

void func(set *a){
         *a=malloc(maxLength*sizeof(set));
               (*a)[0]=10;
               (*a)[1]=13;
               (*a)[2]=15;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    set a;
    func(&a);
    printf("%d %d %d",a[0],a[1],a[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is the problem .. 
and if i add in the pre-compile code : `#include <iostream>`
the error goes , but another error appears:

```
IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "set"
```

**NEW CODE**

```
void func(set *a){
    func(a);
}

void func1(set *a){
        *a=reinterpret_cast<set>(malloc(maxLength*sizeof(set)));
               (*a)[0]=10;
               (*a)[1]=13;
               (*a)[2]=15;
}
```

How do i create an array in a function that called by a function ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems you seem to have. The first and most serious is that you're missing a header file. See e.g. [this `malloc` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). Not including this header file will cause your memory allocations to now work as you expect.

The other error is that you actually seem to be using C++ and not C. [In C you should not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558), but in C++ you *must* do it.

Comment: Still has errors , actually 2 errors:
`IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "set"` 
And second error:
`error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'set'`

Comment: @user3225284 You heard of type-casting? In C a `void *` can be implicitly casted to any other pointer type, and the opposite. However C++ is a much stringer typed language, so you must cast incompatible types. Try e.g. `*a = reinterpret_cast<set>(malloc(...));`

Comment: @user3225284 In C++ you need to cast the returned value of `malloc`

Comment: what is **reinterpret_cast** ?

Comment: @user3225284 It's exactly what it sounds like, it *reinterprets* one type as another. Read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). You might also want to check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  It worked , but only one thing left , I updated the code .. look at it

Answer (score 0):

You should add a header file defining the malloc function: `stdlib.h` (C) or `cstdlib` (C++).

Comment: Why would he need to change the typedef?